# How can I use Incremental Command in GWT

Tags: java, gwt, rpc, gwt-rpc

I have the below code where incremental command is not working as expected. I have the below radio button once it is selected I will get the value from the txt box of product and do an RPC. Based on the output I would like to form the where clause and run the resulting query.

I have the below class variables

```
private static boolean isLoaded = false;

StringBuilder whereClause = new StringBuilder("select * from grocery_shop where ");

StringBuilder productCode = new StringBuilder("(");

ArrayList<String> productList = null;
```

Below code is the place where RPC is called in Incremental command

```
    if (Dialog.getRadioproduct().getValue()) {
        DeferredCommand.addCommand(new IncrementalCommand() {

            @Override
            public boolean execute() {
                if (isLoaded) {
                    ProductServiceAsync Service =
                            ServiceFactory.getService(ProductReportService.class);
                    Service.getBasicProducts(Dialog.getTxtProduct().getValue(),
                        new AsyncCallback<ArrayList<String>>() {

                            @Override
                            public void onServiceFailure(Throwable ex) {
                                showError("Error");
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onServiceSuccess(ArrayList<String> result) {
                                productList = result;
                                while(productList.iterator.hasnext())
                                    whereClause.append(" AND PROD = '" + productList.iterator.next() + "'");
                                isLoaded = true;
                            }
                        });
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
```

I wanted this execute query to be executed after the above RPC is success however the below line is executed before RPC.

```
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(whereClause);
```

Plz let me know if there is anything I have missed.

Answer (score 0):

Well `IncrementalCommand` has been deprecated. Now you should use: `Scheduler.RepeatingCommand` or `Scheduler.scheduleIncremental()`

Apart from that, it is normal the execution of your query before the success answer because RPC is async (a new thread starts on that part), so, you should control your code on the `onServiceSuccess` and `onServiceFailure` (basically do the query on those methods according to your requirements).

Other option is to use the Promises pattern which is implemented on GQuery. something like
doTheRPC(...).done(...).always(...); (but if you do not have much experience on GWT the easiest solution is described above).